# Get all subsets of a Python dictionary with restrictions

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations

I have the following dictionary:

```
intervals = {'param1': [0, 1],
             'param2_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
             'param2_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             'param3_hi': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
             'param3_lo': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
             'param4': [0, 1],
             'param5_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
             'param5_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

How would I create all possible subsets of this dictionary where I must have exactly one of each number x for 'paramx'? Meaning that I can only have one entry for param1 (_lo or _hi), one entry for param2 (_lo or _hi), and so on, and that each subset must include every paramx that does not have a _lo or _hi.

Here are two possible subsets:

```
subset_one = {'param1': [0, 1],
              'param2_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
              'param3_hi': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
              'param4': [0, 1],
              'param5_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}

subset_two = {'param1': [0, 1],
              'param2_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
              'param3_lo': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
              'param4': [0, 1],
              'param5_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}

# Example of mixed '_hi' and '_lo' intervals
subset_three = {'param1': [0, 1],
                'param2_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                'param3_hi': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                'param4': [0, 1],
                'param5_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}

...
```

Note: I want to preserve key, value pairs.

Edit: Added subset_three to show the possibility of having mixed '_lo' and '_hi' intervals.

Comment: Are these the only keys you'd have?

Comment: Is this a finite list of parameters, are those their real names and are they always suffixed with a number in incremental order?

Comment: There could be more (depending on the different runs of my program), but the keys will always be of the form paramx, paramx_lo, paramx_hi where x is some integer.

Comment: @zwer, the suffixed integers will always be incremental. There won't be some skip between the numbers.

Comment: @ToddYoung - Jared Goguen bit me to it - with a small correction from my comment his solution should do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both `collections.defaultdict` and `itertools.product` will be useful here. First, construct a pool that sorts the keys based off what they start with. Then, construct the Cartesian product of these bins.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product

pool = defaultdict(list)
for key in intervals:
    base = key.split('_')[0]
    pool[base].append(key)

subsets = [{key: intervals[key] for key in keys} for keys in product(*pool.values())]

# {'param2_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ... , 'param1': [0, 1]}
# {'param5_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ..., 'param2_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
# and so on...
```

Comment: `itertools.product()` will return a an iterator with tuple elements which will fail in your dict comprehension as `intervals` hold individual keys. You need to double-loop it as: `subsets = [{key: intervals[key] for key in keys} for keys in product(*pool.values())]`

Answer (score 2):

In most simple case you may use the following *dict* comprehensions:

```
subset_1 = {k:v for k,v in intervals.items() if k.endswith('_hi') or not k.endswith('_lo')}
subset_2 = {k:v for k,v in intervals.items() if k.endswith('_lo') or not k.endswith('_hi')}

print(subset_1)
print(subset_2)
```

The output:

```
{'param3_hi': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 'param1': [0, 1], 'param2_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'param4': [0, 1], 'param5_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
{'param2_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'param1': [0, 1], 'param3_lo': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'param4': [0, 1], 'param5_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: There could be some combination of both high and low values. It's only that I must have one of each numbered parameter.

Comment: @ToddYoung, can you update your question with extended and elaborated conditions and desired output?

Comment: Just added  'subset_three', an example where we could have a mixture of '_lo' and '_hi' intervals.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want `itertools.product` applied to the five choice sets in your parameters:

```
choices = [
    ['param1'],
    ['param2_lo', 'param2_hi'],
    ['param3_lo', 'param3_hi'],
    ['param4'],
    ['param5_lo', 'param5_hi']
]

for permute in itertools.product(*choices):
    ....
```

Is that enough to get you going?

Comment: You'd need to use `(*choices)`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best tool to use is itertools.product, one solution would be this:

```
intervals = {'param1': [0, 1],
             'param2_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
             'param2_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             'param3_hi': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
             'param3_lo': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
             'param4': [0, 1],
             'param5_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
             'param5_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}


import itertools

def get_subsets(intervals):

   params_list = set(key.split('_')[0] for key in intervals.keys())

   list_keys = [[x for x in intervals.keys() if x.startswith(param)] for param in params_list]

   subsets = [{x : intervals[x] for x in sublist} for sublist in itertools.product(*list_keys)]

   return subsets

get_subsets(intervals)

# [{'param2_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'param3_hi': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 'param5_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'param1': [0, 1], 'param4': [0, 1]}, {'param2_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'param3_hi': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 'param1': [0, 1], 'param4': [0, 1], 'param5_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and `product` from `itertools` module like this example in order to list all the possible combinations:

```
from itertools import groupby, product

intervals = {'param1': [0, 1],
             'param2_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
             'param2_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             'param3_hi': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
             'param3_lo': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
             'param4': [0, 1],
             'param5_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
             'param5_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}


sub = []

for _,v in groupby(sorted(intervals.keys()), lambda x: x[5]):
    # Or:
    # sub.append(list(v))
    sub.append(sorted(list(v)))


for k in product(*sub):
    print({j:intervals[j] for j in k})
    print("------")
```

Output:

```
{'param1': [0, 1], 'param3_hi': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 'param2_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'param5_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'param4': [0, 1]}
------
{'param1': [0, 1], 'param3_hi': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 'param2_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'param5_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'param4': [0, 1]}
------
{'param1': [0, 1], 'param2_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'param5_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'param3_lo': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'param4': [0, 1]}
------
{'param1': [0, 1], 'param2_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'param3_lo': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'param5_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'param4': [0, 1]}
------
....
------

{'param4': [0, 1], 'param1': [0, 1], 'param5_hi': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'param3_lo': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'param2_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
------
{'param4': [0, 1], 'param1': [0, 1], 'param5_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'param3_lo': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'param2_lo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
------
```